# Pulling images from privately-hosted registry on Openshift deployments always yields "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"

Tags: docker, openshift, x509certificate, docker-registry, redhat-containers

I am trying to deploy apps into an Openshift cluster (using `oc apply -f <deployment-file-name>.yaml`), which involves pulling an image from a privately-hosted registry, and I'm running into the problem in the title. I am logged into the cluster and using `oc` command line tools on a bastion host, which is the only host in the cluster that is not  air-gapped.

A few attempted fixes that haven't worked:

1. Getting a certificate (call it `ca.crt`) signed by the company I work for using an internal tool, generating a file in the format `.pem` (call it `perm.pem`) via the command `openssl x509 -in ca.crt -out perm.pem`, putting `ca.crt` into `/etc/docker/certs.d/<address-of-registry-hosting-machine>:<port>/` on the bastion host, and running the private registry with the command that matches the certificate (`ca.crt`) and its key to the `REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE` and `REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY` env. variables respectively (as demo'ed in the [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#get-a-certificate)).
2. Placing `"insecure-registries":["<address-of-registry-hosting-machine>:<port>"]` into the file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file on the bastion host
3. Creating a configuration map, as instructed [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openshift_container_platform/4.9/html-single/registry/index) on section 2.5, and modifying the deployment YAML file to contain certificate contents (I tried all possible permutations of certificate contents, i.e. with and without root and intermediate certificates).

Does anyone know what else I could do to have deployments from the bastion host overcome the error?

Comment: have you tried installing the CA on the bastion host like any regular Linux host trying to get familiar with a self-signed CA, then restarting the docker daemon and the registry container?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OpenShift everything is pulled by the internal cluster registry. What you need to do is add your company CA which issued the certificate of your private registry to the OpenShift-internal registry. An article how to do that can be found here: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/cicd/builds/setting-up-trusted-ca.html#configmap-adding-ca_setting-up-trusted-ca